ECMWF Web API Python client library
I intend to use ecmwf with API and I am getting this error when I try to call my script, I copied and pasted my KEY API into the main home directory but I keep getting this error:
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[4], line 10
      8 from scipy.ndimage.filters import maximum_filter, minimum_filter
      9 import scipy.ndimage as ndimage
---> 10 from ecmwf.opendata import Client

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ecmwf'


Where is your ecmwf installed?

How have you managed your Python environnement so far ? Pip or Anaconda or something else? Often those errors come from a module being mistakenly installed to another place than the active environnement.
